# Rate limiter algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Let's say I want to write a Rate limiter.
By Rate limiter, I mean that suppose we want that our server should entertain only 5 requests per user in the last 5 minutes.

We have to write a function that returns a boolean that if we can accept the current requests or not?
Which data structure will be used for this? How will we update entries that are more than the last 5 minutes older?

Answer (score 1):

You need a FIFO queue holding a maximum of 5 times.

Upon a request, purge the times older than 5 minutes. Then if there is room left, accept the request and push the current time.

---

**Update:**

To handle the multiple users, it does not seem foolish to hold one queue per user (ring buffer), given that they are short.

Otherwise, you can store all times in a single array and organize them as doubly linked lists, with pointers to the start of the lists, per user.

Answer (score 0):

You need queue with size 5, containing timestamps of requests.

With every request you check if last timestamp younger then 5 min.

- If it does, you fail the request.
- If it doesn't, you remove last element and push new timestamp.

Comment: Five requests are allowed in the last five minutes. Not just one.

Comment: Fixed it. [i need to please validation on minimal comment length]

Comment: Your "fix" is worse.

Comment: Now it fixed. It is actually same as your now :)

Comment: I still disagree with "last timestamp". And your solution keeps more elements in the queue.

Comment: I changed it back to 5. If last timestamp is older then 5 minutes then we have at most 4 request within 5 minutes, so we can proceed. You don't need to check other timestamps.

Comment: I am not alluding to the 5. You keep expired timestamps in the queue. This is harmless but differs from my version.

Comment: Oh. yes. We won't save much memory by purging them slightly early, but my version have advantage of working in constant time, while yours being same time average, may work bit longer some time. In case of 5 records difference is neglectable thou.

Comment: Yep, that's right. (Purging saves no memory at all.) Notice that your use of "last" is quite ambiguous.

Comment: It theoretically could. If we will use linked list to store, and if queue is almost always empty. I don't know how I can word it better. Maybe "check if tail of the queue timestamp is younger then 5 min"?

Comment: What is the head, what is the tail ? You did not even specify the type of queue.

Comment: So for each user, we are creating a separate queue, then how are we gonna find out that for a particular user how many requests are there at a particular time. How will we identify user on basis of id since we are storing only timestamp

Comment: I thought queue is always FIFO, if it is LIFO it is stack. But you right it is unclear which end of queue is tail.

Comment: @Rohit yes, each user get his own queue. We can maintain a map user to queue to be able to tell which queue belongs to which user. We need to purge that map somehow to make sure it doesn't grow indefinitely.